# Buscar palabra en un string en java

Tags: java, bucle-for, condiciones

Hola, actualmente estoy estudiando java, y aun estoy entrando en temas de bucles y etiquetas, y justo me encontre con un ejemplo de como saber cuantas veces la palabra "trigo" aparece en un String; y este es el ejemplo:

```
    public class C10_SentenciaBucleEtiquetasBuscar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String frase = "tres trigotristes tigres tragan trigotrigo en un trigaltrigo";
        String palabra = "trigo";
        int maxPalabra = palabra.length();
        int maxFrase = frase.length() - maxPalabra;
        int cantidad = 0;

        buscar:
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxFrase;) {
            int k = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < maxPalabra; j++) {
                if (frase.charAt(k++) != palabra.charAt(j)) {
                    i++;
                    continue buscar;
                }
            }
            cantidad++;
            i = i + maxPalabra;
        }
        System.out.println("Encontrado = " + cantidad + " veces la palabra " + palabra + " en la frase");
    }
}
```

Pero me estoy perdiendo al tratar de entender la logica; si alguien que logre entenderlo y pueda explicarlo, o incluso hacerlo un poco mas entendible, me ayudaria muchisimo

Comment: Luego de tantos años veo un label en Java...

Answer (score 0):

Para explicarlo hay que usar un concepto que por si solo puede explicar como funciona el bucle, en Java y en muchos otros lenguajes de programación un `String` es un arreglo de caracteres, lo cual quiere decir que:

```
String palabra = "trigo";
```

es igual a:

```
char data[] = {'t', 'r', 'i', 'g', 'o'};
```

Aunque Java lo maneja como un objeto de la clase `String`, internamente (y en su forma mas "primitiva") es un arreglo de caracteres, lo puedes ver acá [Class String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Entonces, para buscar palabras en una frase hay que obtener el número de letras (caracteres) que existen, tanto en la palabra a buscar como en la frase donde se buscará.

Cantidad se inicializa en 0 porque en Java como en otros lenguajes de programación se empieza a contar desde 0, digamos que por ejemplo tienes 100 elementos, entonces `for` iría del 0 al 99.

Luego tenemos `buscar:` el cual es una etiqueta para el bucle.

El primer bucle va a iterar mientras el contador `i` sea igual o menor al largo de la frase (sin la palabra a buscar).

Después tenemos `int k = i`, en este caso la variable `k` se utiliza para seguir buscando palabras en la frase.

En el segundo bucle se itera mientras `j` sea menor al largo de la palabra.

Luego viene el `if`, donde si no coinciden ( es decir `!=`), se va a volver a ejecutar el primer bucle con `continue buscar;` pero cambiando el valor de `i`, es decir pasando a la siguiente letra de la frase, por eso tienes `i++` antes de `continue`. Entonces se ejecuta de nuevo el bucle pero con `i` incrementando en 1 para que no se vuelva a ejecutar sobre la posición anterior, si te das cuenta el primer `for` donde se usa `i` no tiene `i++` como el segundo bucle que si incluye `j++`, lo cual ejecutará el bucle se cumpla o no la condición dentro de el.

**Simplificando**:

Iteras sobre el arreglo de caracteres para encontrar una secuencia de caracteres que coincida con tu otro arreglo de caracteres.

Como extra, puedes imprimir `i` y `j` dentro de cada bucle para ver qué hace exactamente y cómo va iterando.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que pocas veces veo códigos tan abstrusos, es tan intrincado y está tan lejos de ser óptimo que me niego a comentarlo, hasta acá, esto debería estar en la zona de comentarios, pero creo que es válido, presentarte un forma sencilla de obtener lo mismo...

```
public static void mimo() {
   String frase = "tres trigotristes tigres tragan trigotrigo en un trigaltrigo";
   String palabra = "trigo";
   int maxPalabra = palabra.length();
   int maxFrase = frase.length() - maxPalabra;
   int cantidad = 0;
   for( int i = 0; i <= maxFrase;  ) {
      for( int j = 0; j < maxPalabra; j++ ) {
         if( frase.charAt( i + j ) != palabra.charAt( j ) ) {
             i++; 
             j = 0;
             continue;
         }
      }
      cantidad++;
      i += maxPalabra;
   }
   System.out.println( cantidad );
}
```

El bucle exterior itera sobre el texto, mientras que el interior itera sobre la palabra buscada y la compara (letra por letra) con las posiciones siguientes a la que está parado el externo, si alguna de estas comparaciones da "false", se aumenta **i** (para empezar la comparación desde la posición siguiente) y se reinicia **j**.
Si por el contrario, no obtuvimos ningún "false", se suma "1" a **cantidad** y se aumenta **i** con el largo de la palabra buscada (para no hacer búsquedas innecesarias).